# Wiring a bluetooth module into car radio, issue with switching between radio and bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, radio

I have an old Blaupunkt Radio in my 91 VW golf. I have purchased a [Bluetooth module](https://www.ebay.com/itm/LN-BT02-Bluetooth-4-0-Audio-Receiver-Board-Wireless-Stereo-Sound-Module-For-Car-/391810229664) from eBay and I have wired the line out from this into the Left and Right inputs to the amplifier that would normally be used for the outputs from the cassette player. The pre-amp for the cassette player is still wired in also, although the tape reader is disconnected.

From the data sheet for the radio, I can see that when a tape is inserted, the audio source should switch from radio to tape. [Here is a link to the data sheet.](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1en_D_VJRV9ZAh-bLcXZlf8uBwAv7dNRc) On page 5 of the linked PDF, on the top right of the sheet you can see the switching circuit for the audio inputs. I have wired my Bluetooth L and R inputs into R1304 and R1305. The input MS is set high when a tape is inserted into the radio.

The problem that I am having is that the two audio sources are playing through the speakers at the same time.

I have a few theories as to why and wanted to see what others thought:

1. The pre-amp for the cassette player is still connected and is interfering with the switching circuit?
2. The signal from the Bluetooth module isn't the same voltage as the pre-amp for the cassette so the switching circuit isn't functioning correctly?
3. Maybe I need to wire the Bluetooth module line out into the cassette pre-amp?

I have some more testing to do this evening, it was getting late and I ran out of time, but if anyone has any thoughts on this I would greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about electrical engineering, but about performing installations on a car. The question may be on-topic at https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I do not agree, did you read my post in its entirety? The final installation will be in a car but that has no bearing on the project itself. The project is electrical engineering.

Comment: The point is that this question is about the use and installation of existing electronic devices. Plus you would get much better help from people who install these things all day.

Comment: But this isn't specific to car radios. I could be modifying an old walkman. I highly doubt mechanics are soldering bluetooth modules into existing radio headunits.

Comment: This is off topic because it is a *usage* question - if you were *designing your own bluetooth module* and providing *complete internal details* select issues of that might be on-topic.  Of course that is not a wise thing to do for your application - and this is not the right place to ask about it.

Comment: Explicitly on topic here: `except when designing these products or modifying their electronics for other uses`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that the two sources playing at the same time are the radio and the BT stream.

Looking at the schematics at the same page 5, but in the bottom middle of the page, there is a section called LW Mini 14, this is the mechanical tape control part. On pin 1 of the connector, you can clearly see a switch with the symbols of tape and radio. this switch is the mechanical trigger to tell the system to switch from radio to tape.

If you take this pin to ground you should only hear one source, which should be BT or tape, if you have one playing.

If instead you have BT and the tape playing at the same time, then, all you need to do is to put a tape in the radio that doesn't have tape. so no sound will come out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. In relation to putting a tape in to the cassette player I had assumed that the source would switch from tape to radio but that is not the case. With tape in or out, both sources can be heard from the speakers.

Within the section LW Mini 14, you can also see an output MS which is an input to the switching circuit where both the radio and tape inputs are. I am going to probe that this evening and see if it is changing state when a tape is inserted.

Comment: The alternative workaround you could use if everything else fails, is to lift the leg of C1545 and C1566 in the top right section of page 5, and drop in a small relay that switches between the original setup and BT. Then you can control the input by driving the coil of the relay. Even better would be to drop the relay after the preamp, or at least after R1550/R1570, and use the mute voltage to control the relay through a transistor.

Comment: So by removing resistors R1304 and R1305 from the PCB and soldering in the outputs from the Bluetooth module, everything worked as it should. Presumably the Bluetooth module was providing feedback to the cassette decoder and wasn't allowing the switching circuit to function properly.